# Google User Log-In from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-signin

I am making a chrome extension, and for the purposes of my Chrome Extension, I am wanting users to be able to sign in to their Google account so they can send information to a server. I have been reading about user authentication and whatnot from the Google documents, but this is for apps that are being published into the store, and mine is in development. This is brand new territory for me, and I am lost. I feel like there's something that I must be missing, but I don't know how to get started.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular, show all that you tried, and what isnt working on that code. google "chrome identity" and "chrome extension oauth"

Comment: @ZigMandel I appreciate your help! I'm new to this whole thing, stack overflow questions, web development, so I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked) about the quick way of loading up your working directory for testing. Extensions that you download from the Chrome Web Store are packaged up as `.crx` files, which is great for distribution, but not so great for development.